# Replace String with html element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the right way to replace a pure String with an HTML element in jsx? The following code just displays String `<span>...`, not an HTML element.

```
 let spanEl = JSON.stringify(jsonObj).replace("Hello World", `<span className="inlineContainer">Hello World!</span>`)
```

Comment: The problem should be at the place where you use your edited string. Please share it.

Answer (score 1):

From React docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html):

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

The React team calls it `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` because adding the Html as a string is risky for cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks. That's why it's important to sanitize the Html string before passing it to dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

You could use some 3rd party library, but most will do the same thing under the hood.

To sanitize the Html string without 3rd party libraries, you can use this function:

```
const sanitize = (html = '') => {
  const txt = document.createElement('textarea');

  txt.innerHTML = html;

  return txt.value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess to are trying to directly display the spanEl  variable in dom which is causing the issue. Either you can use library like **react-html-parser** to parse string to jsx element or use **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** property to use string as jsx.